# how to use WhirlyGlobe-maply properly in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d

When I get users' data, how can I read them and modify the earth?
For example,i have been to NewYork and Washington so I want to change the colors of these places on the map.How to do it

Comment: You can try spriteKit.

Comment: Here's a link to a SceneKit tuorial for rendering a 3D earth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2UWvR2nR0A

Comment: This question is too broad. Yes, you can use OpenGL, Metal, SceneKit or other frameworks to do this, although you'll need more than that in order for the usr to be able to drag/rotate/enlarge the model. SceneKit is probably the easiest way to go since it's designed to do the sort of thing you want to do easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongst an overwhelming number of options available to create your Earth, if simplicity / ease-of-use is what you are looking for, take a look into **WhirlyGlobe**. It's simple, easy to use, easy to *setup*, and fairly powerful for many needs.

[WhirlyGlobe-Maply SDK](http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/)